# Discrepancy in Scikit Learn Stratified Cross Validation

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, cross-validation

I am seeing a discrepancy between classification performance between two cross validation technique using the same data. I was wondering if anyone can shed some light on this.

- Method 1: cross_validation.train_test_split
- Method 2: StratifiedKFold.

## Two Examples with same data set

Data Set 5500[n_samples :: Class 1 = 500 ; Class 0 = 5000 ] by 193 Features

## Method 1 [ Random Iteration with train_test_split ]

```
for i in range(0,5):
    X_tr, X_te, y_tr, y_te = cross_validation.train_test_split(X_train.values, y_train, test_size=0.2, random_state=i)
    clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=250, max_depth=None, min_samples_split=1, random_state=0, oob_score=True)
    y_score = clf.fit(X_tr, y_tr).predict(X_te)
    y_prob = clf.fit(X_tr, y_tr).predict_proba(X_te)
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_te, y_score)
    print cm
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_te,y_prob[:,1])
    roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr);
    print "ROC AUC: ", roc_auc
```

## Result of method 1

```
Iteration 1 ROC AUC:  0.91
[[998   4]
 [ 42  56]]

Iteration 5 ROC AUC:  0.88
[[1000    3]
 [  35   62]]
```

## Method 2 [ StratifiedKFold cross validation ]

```
cv = StratifiedKFold(y_train, n_folds=5,random_state=None,shuffle=False)
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=250, max_depth=None, min_samples_split=1, random_state=None, oob_score=True)
for train, test in cv:
    y_score = clf.fit(X_train.values[train], y_train[train]).predict(X_train.values[test])
    y_prob = clf.fit(X_train.values[train], y_train[train]).predict_proba(X_train.values[test])
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_train[test], y_score)
    print cm
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_train[test],y_prob[:,1])
    roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr);
    print "ROC AUC: ", roc_auc
```

## Result of method 2

```
Fold 1 ROC AUC:  0.76
Fold 1 Confusion Matrix
[[995   5]
 [ 92   8]]

Fold 5 ROC AUC:  0.77
Fold 5 Confusion Matrix
[[986  14]
 [ 76  23]]
```

Answer (score 3):

train_test_split is not stratified. In the current development version and in the upcoming 0.17 you can do `stratify=y` to make it stratified, but not in 0.16.2.
Also the random states are not fixed and used differently, so you can't expect the exact same outcome.

Comment: Hi Andreas,
Thanks for your reply. 


 I am more concerned about the consistent better classification result  by any cross_val.train_test_split compared to stratifiedkfold. I can see that train_test_split maintained class balance, which makes it comparable to stratifiedkfold [I do not expect exactly same result]. 


 My question is, why stratifiedkfold fail to produce a single fold that shows classification result close to cross_validation.train_test_split. 


I moved from sklearn-0.14.1 to 0.16.1 and noticing this performance drop using stratifiedkfold on same data and folds. 


Thanks again.

Comment: Ah. Then that means there are correlations in your data. Do shuffle=True in StratifiedKFold to get the same results. But you should find out why there is an order in your data. Also, train_test_split doesn't preserve class balances.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
[ Positive data ] First 500 
[ Negative data ] 501 - 5000 contains . 

Changing shuffle=True did the trick. Below is result of 5 folds with shuffle True and False. 

[   Result With shuffle=True  ]
ROC AUC:  0.951, 0.950, 0.956, 0.958, 0.955

 and [   Result With shuffle=False  ]
ROC AUC :  0.719, 0.915, 0.835, 0.723, 0.662

I thought order of the label data does not impact fold or classification performance. 
[1] . Does the fold selection happen sequentially ot randomly ?  
[2]. Would it be possible to explain why does this impact fold selection.

Comment: The folds are as contiguous as possible (when stratifying). Without stratification it is just the first n / k samples in the first fold etc. shuffle means shuffling the data before splitting, so the folds are random.